# Disabling localization for specific apps in Django

Tags: django, localization

Is there a way to disable localization for specific apps in settings for Django?

There are two possible reasons for this:

- Switch off localization in admin apps eg  contrib/admin because admins would prefer to use English rather than the local language.
- Some app default translations are really bad and confusing, and we would like to keep them off during development until we get to doing our own proper translation.

I know we can just delete the translation files or other hacks maybe, but having this in settings is more convenient when we're doing frequent upgrades.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such setting to disable translation for specific apps.

Regarding your first use-case, having admin in another language is easily achived with custom middleware, check this snippet:

http://source.mihelac.org/2009/11/12/django-set-language-for-admin/

If url scheme of 3rd party apps are simple, maybe you can use same approach to set different (default) language for them.

Comment: The URL based technique for admin is interesting. The other case is really a convenience matter in case of repeat updates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable [`LocaleMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), you can then set the appropriate cookie or session variable for that user. I usually implement a drop down with the available languages for the system. User selects the language, and based on that I set the session or cookie for that user. This allows the admin to remain in English while the other areas are translated.

Here is the order of lookup (from the docs):

```
First, it looks for a django_language key in the current user's session.

Failing that, it looks for a cookie.

The name of the cookie used is set by the LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME setting.
(The default name is django_language.)

Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This header is sent
by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you prefer, in order by
priority. Django tries each language in the header until it finds one with
available translations.

Failing that, it uses the global LANGUAGE_CODE setting.
```

#### EDIT:

It is not possible through settings; however depending on how you are using the app - you can "force" translation of only the language you want. This can cause problems if your languages are RTL (display problems).

The solution you hinted at (deleting the actual gettext translation files), is one way, but not recommended.

Since the displaying of translated text is a function of the template engine, simply overriding the templates of those applications and disabling the translation tags should do what you want, and is more portable.

Comment: Your answer is about selecting locales per user, this is well documented. My question is whether it's possible to switch off localization per *specific app* in settings. Apps come with their own translation files and these are what we want to selectively disable. Admin users is just one case I discussed, we want them to see the site localized, but what's coming from a specific app (in this case admin) to be unlocalized, and we want to be able to do this in settings. The question is whether this is possible. Regards.