# Django- Multiple languages on the same site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My issue has to do with a Django site running using one language, and using specific languages for specific apps

My example is:

I want to run a 'pt-pt' (Portuguese- Portugal) Django site. In it, I'm using a 3rd party App that has pt-BR (Portuguese- Brazil) as an available language, but no pt-pt translation. Lacking, pt-pt, pt-BR would be better than English.

I can set the language as:

```
#settings.py...

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-pt'
```

But then the site Admin uses pt-pt and the App uses English (undesirable).

If I set it to pt-BR I'll get pt-BR on the site (undesirable) and pt-BR on the App.

So I read Django's Docs again and tried the [Languages setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGES)

```
#settings.py...

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt'

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = (
    ('pt', _('Portuguese')),
    ('pt-br', _('Brazilian Portuguese')),
)
```

to no avail (nothing changed). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I understood correctly that you would prefer your site to be pt-pt and the app to be pt-BR, then I think that you can set pt-pt in you site's settings file and pt-BR in the app's setting file. If that won't work, maybe this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755613/disabling-localization-for-specific-apps-in-django

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best option is to copy the locale files of the pt-BR app to the project root locale directory. Then rename the folder from pt-BR to pt-pt and when you browse the site as pt-pt it will include that particular locale file.

Another option would be to use activate('pt-BR') in the pt-BR app but that would not be very conveniant.